# How to pass result as it comes using coroutines?

Tags: asynchronous, kotlin, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines

Let's say I have list of repos. I want to iterate through all of them. As each repo returns with result, I wanted to pass it on.

```
val repos = listOf(repo1, repo2, repo3)
val deferredItems = mutableListOf<Deferred<List<result>>>()

repos.forEach { repo ->
    deferredItems.add(async { getResult(repo) })
}

val results = mutableListOf<Any>()
deferredItems.forEach { deferredItem ->
    results.add(deferredItem.await())
}

println("results :: $results")
```

In the above case, It waits for each repo to return result. It fills the `results` in sequence, result of `repo1` followed by result of `repo2`. If `repo1` takes more time than `repo2` to return result, we will be waiting for `repo1`'s result even though we have result for `repo2`.

Is there any way to pass the result of `repo2` as soon as we have the result?

Answer (score 3):

The `Flow` API supports this almost directly:

```
repos.asFlow()
        .flatMapMerge { flow { emit(getResult(it)) } }
        .collect { println(it) }
```

`flatMapMerge` first collects all the `Flow`s that come out of the lambda you pass to it and then *concurrently* collects those and sends them into the downstream as soon as any of them completes.

Answer (score 1):

That's what channels are for:

```
val repos = listOf("repo1", "repo2", "repo3")
val results = Channel<Result>()
repos.forEach { repo ->
    launch {
        val res = getResult(repo)
        results.send(res)
    }
}

for (r in results) {
    println(r)
}
```

This example is incomplete, as I don't close the channel, so the resulting code will be forever suspended. Make sure that in your real code you close the channel once all results are received:

```
val count = AtomicInteger()

for (r in results) {
    println(r)
    if (count.incrementAndGet() == repos.size) {
        results.close()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use `Channels`.

```
suspend fun loadReposConcurrent() = coroutineScope {
    val repos = listOf(repo1, repo2, repo3)
    val channel = Channel<List<YourResultType>>()

    for (repo in repos) {
        launch {
            val result = getResult(repo)
            channel.send(result)
        }
    }

    var allResults = emptyList<YourResultType>()
    repeat(repos.size) {
        val result = channel.receive()
        allResults = allResults + result

        println("results :: $result")
        //updateUi(allResults)
    }
}
```

in the code above in `for (repo in repos) {...}` loop all the requests calculated in seprate coroutines with `launch` and as soon as their result is ready will send to `channel`.

in `repeat(repos.size) {...}` the `channel.receive()` waits for new values from all coroutines and consumes them.