# Is there a more idiomatic way to perform a subscribe & async / await operation?

Tags: kotlin, websocket, kotlin-coroutines, completable-future

I have a spring boot kotlin app that creates a web socket connection to another spring app, sends multiple "subscribe" messages, and then needs to wait for receipt of one response per subscription on the web socket connection. The number of subscriptions open at a given time could be up to a few thousand.

I've come up with a basic working solution using CompletableFuture and coroutines, as below. Is there a more idiomatic or concise way to do this task, or is this a fine solution? Any suggestions for improvement are appreciated.

```
// InputObject / ResponseObject are generic placeholders
fun getItems(inputObjects: List<InputObject>): List<ResponseObject> {
    val ret: ConcurrentLinkedQueue<ResponseObject> = ConcurrentLinkedQueue()

    // create a completable future for each input object
    val subscriptions: MutableMap<String, CompletableFuture<ResponseObject>> = mutableMapOf()
    inputObjects.forEach {
        subscriptions[it.id] = CompletableFuture()
    }

    // create web socket client configured with a lambda handler to
    // fulfill each subscription
    // each responseObject.id matches one inputObject.id
    val client = createWebSocketClient({
        try {
            val responseObject = objectMapper.readValue(it, ResponseObject::class.java)
            subscriptions[responseObject.id]?.complete(responseObject)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            logger.warn("Exception reading data: ${e.message}")
        }
    })

    runBlocking {
        coroutineScope {
            for (item in inputObjects) {
                launch {
                    // create and send a subscribe request
                    client.sendMessage(createSubscribe(item.id))

                    // wait for each future to complete
                    // uses CompletableFuture extension await() from kotlinx-coroutines-jdk8
                    val result = subscriptions[item.id]?.await()
                    if (result != null) {
                        ret.add(result)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    client.close()

    return ret.toList()
}
```

edit: I found a similar question: [How to pass result as it comes using coroutines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59584379/how-to-pass-result-as-it-comes-using-coroutines)

Which options makes the most sense?

Comment: The code here doesn't seem to care about the association between results and their respective input, because the final list doesn't respect the input order. I guess you could simply use a `channelFlow` and `take()` as many elements as there are inputs.

Comment: I guess the question here is do you really need to match IDs at any point? Or could you just fire your N subscriptions and wait for N responses?

Comment: Is your goal simply to run these requests in parallel but you want your function as a whole to be blocking? Typically, `runBlocking` is never used because it defeats the purpose of using coroutines in the first place.

Comment: @Joffrey I'll take a look at `channelFlow`, thanks for the tip. Correct, I do not actually need to match the IDs. I could just collect the results at the end of the process.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I guess OP would still benefit from running all requests concurrently or in parallel, even if the method is blocking as a whole. But I agree it would be even better to have this whole method `suspend`.

Comment: @Moot as a side note `runBlocking` + `coroutineScope` is kinda pointless. You can remove `coroutineScope` here

Comment: @Tenfour04 yes, I'd like the surrounding function to be blocking as it's part of a multi-step synchronous request

Comment: You can have multi-step synchronous behaviour with a sequence of `suspend` function calls. You don't need to actually block threads to have the calls execute in a sequence

Comment: I don't know Spring Boot so I don't know if there's a better way to be getting your asynchronous results. But if you just want to wait for a bunch of CompleteableFutures, I don't know why coroutines would be introduced rather than just combining your futures and retrieving the results synchronously with `get()`.

Answer (score 1):

```kotlin
fun getItems(inputObjects: List<InputObject>): List<ResponseObject> {
    val subscriptions = ids.associateTo(mutableMapOf()) { it.id to CompletableFuture<ResponseObject>() }

    val client = createWebSocketClient({
        try {
            val responseObject = objectMapper.readValue(it, ResponseObject::class.java)
            subscriptions[responseObject.id]?.complete(responseObject)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            logger.warn("Exception reading data: ${e.message}")
        }
    })

    return runBlocking(Dispatchers.IO) {
      inputObjects
        .mapNotNull {
            client.sendMessage(createSubscribe(item.id))
            subscriptions[item.id]?.await()
        }
    }
}
```